# C# join 2 DataTables without LINQ

Tags: c#, join, datatable

I want to join two data tables using C# without using LINQ. How can I do it?

Comment: do the tables have the same schema?

Comment: what do you have against linq?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to concatenate two datatables to a new one? If so, do this

```
DataTable result= table1.Copy();
result.Merge(table2);
```

where table1 and table2 are DataTables

Answer (score -1):

use a single statment that joins the tables in SQL, i.e.

```
select * from table1 t1, table2, t2 where t1.id = t2.id
```

HTH

Ivo Stoykov

Comment: Hello, I want to use C#, not SQL Server